# SharePoint list - Simple Row Numbering/Auto

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I cannot find any simple answer for this.

I have a SharePoint list. I need to have a column that will show row number that starts from 1 and  then auto increments for the next rows  2,3,4,5 etc.
and for example if you delete row number 25 the row 26 will change to 25 etc.

How can I achieve this ?

The default ID column does not Update when row is deleted, so currently my list starts from 7,653.
Is there a way to make ID column work normally?

Comment: Very good answers, the problem is that the result does not generate a number that can be used, it is only graphic, in my case I would need it to generate a number that can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with user79408, you can achieve your needs through Column JSON Formatting.

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Create a **Single line of tex**t column. In my test, this column named [DocId]

[image]

2.**Column settings** >> **Format this column**

[image]

3.On the Format Column windows, select "**Advanced mode**" link

[image]

4.Paste the below JSON formatting

`Note:`**@rowIndex** starts from 0 by default and sets the increment to **1**.

[image]

5.Here is my test:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only need it for display purposes, you could use column formatting to meet your needs.

If you're unfamiliar with column formatting, have a read of the documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

The key to your requirements is to leverage the `@rowIndex` and add 1, as the index starts at 0.

Something like this should work. The important part is in the `txtContent` section of the code below, the rest is just styling. You could either apply this formatting to an existing column or create a new column, depending on your preferences and requirements.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px"
      },
      "txtContent": {
        "operator": "+",
        "operands": [
          "@rowIndex",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```