# Sharepoint Lists - Custom ID column

Tags: list

I've been searching online for a few days now and could not find a solution to this.
I basically intend to add a custom ID column which reorganizes itself upon any item inclusion or deletion. I found a post that solves the deletion problem ([SharePoint list - Simple Row Numbering/Auto](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299475/sharepoint-list-simple-row-numbering-auto)) but that solution does not address the problem of adding an entry with an existing ID that can fall in between the existing sequence. For example, say I have IDs 50 and 51, if I were to add a new line with a custom ID of "50", the column would add a "+1" to the previous "50" and anything after it all the way to the end of the list, hence readjusting all entries subsequent to the new one I've added. Ideally lists could have the functionality of adding entries in between existing rows but that does not look an available option right now. Has anyone faced this who could provide an insight? Any help is appreciated! Cheers, Rich